# Mounting successively in fstab: wait for partition to be mounted?

Tags: mount, fstab, bind-mount

I mount successively two points using `fstab` in my linux system

```
# Mounting apps drive
UUID=c54ca7da-117d-4cb2-8897-019ba4f6f12d /media/user/apps ext4 defaults 0 2
# Mounting opt based on apps mountpoint
/media/user/apps/opt /opt none bind
```

As you can see, the second mountpoint `/opt` is mounted on the previous mounted partition `/media/user/apps/`. I am not sure, whether it is safe to do like that. I am asking, if I should add some kind of condition or waiting time before I mount `/opt`. If the first `fstab` command is not yet completed and then the second command tries to `bind` there might be a problem, is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/media/user/apps/opt /opt none bind,x-systemd.requires=/media/user/apps
```

Should do the trick.

There are two more options that help doing a safe successive mounting, because when we need to specify order dependencies between mount commands and other units.

- `x-systemd.after`
- `x-systemd.before`

So we can add

```
/media/user/apps/opt /opt none bind,x-systemd.after=/media/user/apps
```

But also, equivalently,

```
UUID=c54ca7da-117d-4cb2-8897-019ba4f6f12d /media/user/apps ext4 defaults,x-systemd.before=/opt 0 2
```

More information at [systemd.mount](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html)

Comment: Exactly this type of commands is what I needed. Thanks, I have saved valuable time searching in the Internet.

Comment: For users hoping this will help solving separate `/usr` partition issues : it won’t.  See [Booting Without /usr is Broken](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/).